# How do I write code that lets the user choose what vowel(s) he wants to delete? (Python)

Tags: python

I am writing code for a final project, which is an app that allows users to design their own license plate.

I want to write code that would basically allow the user to input an English word (which would be fewer than or equal to 10 characters long), then the app asks him if he wants to remove specific vowels from the word, then the app outputs the final word.

Because I am a beginner, I only know how to write code that would omit ALL vowels in whatever the user inputs. Ya feel?

The code I have tried so far:

```
keepOrDeleteVowel1 = input("Would you like to delete the vowels?  Type 'yes' to delete vowels, or 'no' to type a new word.")
                if keepOrDeleteVowel1 == "no" or "No" or "NO":
                    print("This is your word: " + original +  "." + " Enjoy your new license plate! Thank you for using this app.")
                    break
                elif keepOrDeleteVowel1 == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
                    firstLetter = original[0]
                    lastLetter = original[len(original)]
                    if firstLetter != "A" or firstLetter != "E" or firstLetter != "I" or firstLetter != "O" or firstLetter != "U" \
                    or lastLetter != "A" or lastLetter != "E" or lastLetter != "I" or lastLetter != "O" or lastLetter != "U":
                        original =original.remove("A")
                        original =original.remove("E")
                        original =original.remove("I")
                        original =original.remove("O")
                        original =original.remove("U")
                        print (original)
```

Sorry about the formatting.  The code presented above should work to delete all vowels but only if the word does not start or end with a vowel.  But I want to change this so to allow the user to delete vowels himself rather than having the program delete all vowels.

Please respond in detail, much appreciated.

Comment: could you share any code what have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you delete ALL vowels?

Comment: If you know how to ask the user to input a word, do the same thing to ask the user to input a vowel.

Comment: `if keepOrDeleteVowel1 == "no" or "No" or "NO"` is always `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user for a vowel the same way you asked them for the original word, through `input()`. When you have saved that into a variable you can check to make sure that they have entered a vowel, if so you can go ahead and remove it like I've shown below. In order to avoid typing each vowel in lower and upper case while comparing I convert their input to lowercase with `lower()`, you can do the same for'no' as well.

```
vowel = input("Please, type the vowel.")
if vowel.lower() in "aeiou":
    newOrig = original.replace(vowel, "")
    print(newOrig)

else: 
    print("You have not entered a vowel.")
```

Comment: Thank you @t.m.adam I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
initial_word = input("Type the word: ")
vowel = input("Do you want to remove any vowel? If yes, type the vowel you want to remove: ")
if type(vowel) is str:
    if len(vowel) == 1:
        initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.lower(), '')
        initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.upper(), '')
    else:
        print('Wrong input.')
print('The word is: ' + initial_word)
```

Output:

```
Type the word: AaxeyEizIoucU
Do you want to remove any vowel? If yes, type the vowel you want to remove: e
The word is: AaxyizIoucU
```